# Is it possible to put notes in the tool bar of Pycharm/Other tools

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, ide

A suggestion, oftentimes I switch between editors depending on the task I am working on but I find that the often used keyboard shortcuts that I become trained to use for one editor starts to mess up my ability to use the keyboard shortcuts for another editor. So I thought that there is so much space at the top of the application near the toolbar to put down notes for shortcuts I use very often for that application.

For example, opening a resource in

- Pycharm is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>
- Eclipse is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>
- Vscode/Visual Studio is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>

Anyways switching between editors and forgetting what keys does what becomes a bit of mental cost at some point and then shifting through various combinations become ineffective and creates frustration. It would be easier if I could just add the action "text" and shortcut "text" near the top of the IDE. Curious if such a feature exists in Pycharm or any other tool?

Unfortunately, the alternative I could do is edit all tools to key bind specifically to my specifications which maybe an option if I ever can get a good set of key binds I prefer along side with the config files I would need to do it.

Comment: Many IDEs, including the ones that JetBrains puts out, have the option to set your keymap to one that's based on another IDE. PhpStorm, for instance, has ones that are based on Windows, Eclipse, Emacs, NetBeans, Sublime Text and Visual Studio. And, usually, you can copy a keymap and further customize it from there.

Answer (score 0):

Well this is an old question, but still answering. No, there is no such feature in PyCharm to do such a thing as stated in the question.

But a solution to the problem is to use **Find Action** whose shortcut key is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>. Or even simpler, one can press <kbd>Shift</kbd> twice and then go in the **Actions** menu. After this one has to just search the action one wants to perform, and also this menu shows the shortcut key for actions.

Also, PyCharm's GUI is vast, so one need not necessarily use keyboard shortcuts (but yeah, this is not useful if work speed matters a lot)

Comment: Yea I think the annoying part is that everyone is a bit different and so muscle memory gets in the way sometimes when switching between tools.